# How can I prevent Laravel 6.x Queue scheduler from trying the same Job ID multiple times?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm noticing Laravel is creating duplicate jobs of the same ID, for example in the list below you can see job ID 306 was tried twice (as well as 296,298,305)

```
[2021-03-12 20:28:04][296] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:04][297] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:04][298] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:04][299] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:23][297] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:23][300] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:39][301] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:57][301] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:28:57][302] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:15][299] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:15][303] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:35][300] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:35][296] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:36][296] Failed:     App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:36][298] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:36][298] Failed:     App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:36][304] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:44][304] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:29:44][305] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:30:05][302] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:30:05][306] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:12][303] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:12][305] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:13][305] Failed:     App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:13][306] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:13][306] Failed:     App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:13][307] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:43][305] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:43][308] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:46][308] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:46][309] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:50][309] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:32:50][310] Processing: App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:33:05][306] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:33:09][307] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
[2021-03-12 20:33:30][310] Processed:  App\Jobs\RunImport
```

This log was taken from the output sent to supervisor

```
[program:laravel-import]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/myapp/myapp-console/current/artisan queue:work --queue=import --tries=1 --timeout=21600 -vvv
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=myapp
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/myapp/myapp-console/current/storage/logs/worker-import.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

I have the following schedule in `Kernel.php`.  A datasource is a client specific endpoint where they can set a schedule to have an import be run

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
  // start jobs on import queue from user defined schedule
  $datasources = Datasource::all();
  foreach ($datasources as $datasource) {
    if (!empty($datasource->schedule) && $datasource->company->active) {
      $schedule->call(function() use ($datasource) {
        Log::channel('import-runtime')->info("Creating new import for {$datasource->datasource_key}");
        $datasource->createImport();
      })->name("datasource-{$datasource->id}")->withoutOverlapping()->cron($datasource->schedule)->runInBackground();
    }
  }
}
```

The `createImport()` function adds a job to a worker queue

```
public function createImport($onDemand = false) {
  $import = new Import();
  $import->datasource_id = $this->id;
  $import->status = 'awaiting';
  $import->start_at = Carbon::now();
  $import->save();
  $queue = $onDemand ? 'import-ondemand' : 'import';
  Log::channel('import-runtime')->info("[ds_{$import->datasource_id}_import_{$import->id}] Import created, adding to queue {$queue}");
  RunImport::dispatch($import)->onQueue($queue);
}
```

I set everyones schedule to the same cron format `'28 20 * * *'` and let the workers consume all jobs.  I then get errors of `Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException`

How can I prevent these jobs from being tried multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Changing to redis did not solve this issue, same duplicates.  However I found the root cause.  Looks like setting `--timeout=` on the queue has no bearing on `retry_after` inside of `config/queue.php`

If you have long running jobs you must **both** set the `--timeout` and the `retry_after` to your expected maximum duration.

I went ahead and created another connection in `queue.php` for the long running processes and then in supervisor made sure it then used that long running queue instead of the standard one that uses the default of 90 seconds